# no pager using ngtable and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have an ng-table in my project. My problem is that no pager displays. The table loads multiple rows and I paged from 10 to 10, I assign value 10 to count, but nothing happens.

This is my code:

```js
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 10,
    filter: {
        message: ''
    },
    sorting: {
        asset: 'asc'
    }
  },
  {
    total: $scope.data.length,
    counts: [],
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
      var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
          $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
          $scope.data;

      params.total(orderedData.length);
      $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

```html
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <tr ng-repeat="ws in data | filter:search" style="text-align:center;">
    <td data-title="'Tag Name'" sortable="'tagname'">{{ws.tagname}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Description'" sortable="'tagname'">{{ws.tagdescription}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Data Type'" sortable="'datatype'">{{ws.datatype}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Tag Unit'" sortable="'tagdescription'">{{ws.tagunit}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Birth Date'" sortable="'birthdate'">{{ws.birthdate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Last Date'" sortable="'lastdate'">{{ws.lastdate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Last Value'" sortable="'lastvalue'">{{ws.lastvalue}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try repeating over `$data` instead of `data` in your table:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">


<tr ng-repeat="ws in $data | filter:search" style="text-align:center;">
    <td data-title="'Tag Name'" sortable="'tagname'">{{ws.tagname}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Description'" sortable="'tagname'">{{ws.tagdescription}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Data Type'" sortable="'datatype'">{{ws.datatype}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Tag Unit'" sortable="'tagdescription'">{{ws.tagunit}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Birth Date'" sortable="'birthdate'">{{ws.birthdate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Last Date'" sortable="'lastdate'">{{ws.lastdate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Last Value'" sortable="'lastvalue'">{{ws.lastvalue}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`$data` is used internally by `ngTable` to handle pagination among other things.